# Show that if for $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $0 = f(a) $ for a monic polynomial $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x] $, then $a \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> I. Show that if for $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $0 = f(a) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] $ for a monic polynomial, then in fact $a \in \mathbb{Z}.$
>
> II. The set of algebraic integers of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Z}.$

Question: Would proving statement $II.$ also prove $I?$

Proof $I.$ Express $a = \frac{p}{q}$ as a completely reduced rational in $\mathbb{Q}$ and assume to the contrary that $a \not \in \mathbb{Z} \Longrightarrow q \ne \pm 1.$ Observe that the rational number $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q},$ is a solution to $qx-p=0$, where $qx-p \in \mathbb{Z}[x].$ Thus every $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ is algebraic. For an integer monic polynomial $0 = m(x) = x^n + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0  \in \mathbb{Z}[x],$ one has $m \left(\frac{p}{q} \right) = \left(\frac{p}{q} \right)^n + \cdots + a_1 \frac{p}{q} + a_0 \Longrightarrow p^n + \cdots + a_1 p + a_0 = 0 \Longrightarrow p^n \equiv 0 \mod q.$ Since $q \ne \pm 1 \Longrightarrow q$ has a prime factor $v \Longrightarrow v \mid a^n \Longrightarrow v \mid a.$ Thus $v$ is a factor of both $p$ and $q$ contradicting the assumption that $\frac{p}{q}$ is completely reduced. $\Rightarrow \Leftarrow \hspace{1mm} \Box$

Comment: Now that that's out of the way - you had the correct definition of "algebraic number," but we aren't talking about those, we are talking about "algebraic integers." Do you know the definition of algebraic integer?

Comment: They say the same thing.

Comment: @anon Yes, complex number that is a root to a integer monic polynomial.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Okay thank you

Comment: You are welcome. As to the proof (of either)  it has much the same flavour as the standard proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.